# Cucumber Java - ExtendedCucumberOptions does nothing in Runner class (Reports)

Tags: java, cucumber, pom.xml, runner

I'm working with Cucumber in Java, and I have a doubt about the ExtendedCucumberOptions, because is not doing anything.

This is my Runner:

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.testng.CucumberFeatureWrapper;
import cucumber.api.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.ExtendedCucumber;
import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.ExtendedCucumberOptions;
import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.ExtendedTestNGRunner;


@ExtendedCucumberOptions(jsonReport = "target/cucumber-reports/rodriguito/cucumber.json",
        retryCount = 3,
        detailedReport = true,
        detailedAggregatedReport = true,
        overviewReport = true,
        coverageReport = true,
        jsonUsageReport = "target/cucumber-usage/cucumber-usage.json",
        usageReport = true,
        toPDF = true,
        excludeCoverageTags = {"@flaky" },
        includeCoverageTags = {"@passed" },
        outputFolder = "target",
        reportPrefix = "results-${user}")

@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resource/features"},
                 glue={"stepdefs"},
                 monochrome = true,
                 tags = {"~@Ignore"},
                 plugin = {"pretty","html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty",
                           "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
                           "rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt",
                           "usage:target/cucumber-usage.json"}
)
public class TestRunner extends ExtendedTestNGRunner{
    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Feature", dataProvider = "features")
    public void feature(CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runCucumber(cucumberFeature.getCucumberFeature());
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] features() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideFeatures();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }
}
```

Runner is generating the @CucumberOptions except the  "usage:target/cucumber-usage.json"}
By other hand, the @ExtendedCucumberOptions is not working.

This is my POM

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cl.cooper</groupId>
    <artifactId>automation_test_cucumber</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <cucumber.version>1.2.5</cucumber.version>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>

            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.stephenc.monte</groupId>
            <artifactId>monte-screen-recorder</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.16</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-sandwich</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reports</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>automation_test_cucumber</projectName>  <!-- Replace with project name -->
                            <outputDirectory>target/cucumber-reports/advanced-reports</outputDirectory>
                            <cucumberOutput>target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json</cucumberOutput>
                            <buildNumber>42</buildNumber>
                            <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.${java.version}</source>
                    <target>1.${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What I want to do is generate reports different than "pretty". I'm only working with Cucumber without Jenkins. I was trying to create graphic reports, but the ExtendedCucumber is not generating anything in target folder.

I don't know if it were useful, but this is the testng.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="BDD Test Suite" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="1" configfailurepolicy="continue">
    <test name="Login and Update Profile Test" annotations="JDK" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="TestRunner"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Please, I need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is only applicable for Junit while you are using TestNG.

You need to shift from TestNG to Junit if you want this functionality work

Source:

https://github.com/mkolisnyk/cucumber-reports/issues/167